# What type of files can be signed with codesign on a Mac?

Tags: macos, digital-signature

I have an xml document I would like to package and sign on the Mac. I know on Windows you can sign exes, dlls, cabs, and ocxs with signtool, but so far I've only been able to sign .apps on Mac. What other types of files can be signed with codesign on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Everything. If you read Apple's documentation on [what to code sign](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW5), they say:

> You sign all the individual components of your app, leaving no gaps,
>   including:
>
> - **Nested code**. First, you recursively sign all of the helpers, tools,
>     libraries, frameworks, and other components that your app relies on,
>     and that are bundled with your app. See Ensuring Proper Code
>     Signatures for Nested Code for a discussion of how to properly embed
>     and sign nested code in your app bundle. Also see Using Library
>     Validation for additional information about verifying libraries as a
>     matter of system policy.
> - **Mach-O executables**. The signing software
>     applies individual signatures to each architectural component of a
>     universal binary that represents the main executable of your app.
>     These are independent, and usually only the native architecture on the
>     end user's system is verified. To apply the signature, the codesign
>     utility adds the signature directly to the executable file.
> - **Resources**. Everything in an application bundle that is not explicit 
>     code (either
>     nested code bundles or the main executable) is a resource, and all
>     resources are signed. The resource files themselves are not modified
>     as a result of signing. Instead, codesign places the digital
>     signatures corresponding to all the application bundle’s non-code
>     files in a special plist file within the bundle, namely
>     Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources. The codesign utility places the
>     signatures of any nested code here as well, which is why nested code
>     is signed first.